# How to move around with the mouse in a Web Clip Widget?

Tags: dashboard-widget

I have created a Clip Web dashboard with a selection of a web site that shows a google maps with special spots. How can I move the map around in that widget ?

The only thing I managed to do is to move the widget itself :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall, Web Clip Widgets are 100% non-input interactive. They will show automatic changes/animations (javascript/AJAX fired events, animated GIFs, etc.), but they do not allow you to interact with the web page. Generally speaking, that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hopefully there are those navigation buttons on the top left of google maps. Those buttons are responding to clicks, so I'm able to navigate "old-fashinoned" way, but that's more than nothing :-)

Comment: Buttons work but the canvas doesn't? Hmm, that's really interesting. I didn't think that'd be the case. Given that widgets are supposed to be freely moveable, I'm fairly confident in saying that the "old-fashioned way" is as good as you're going to get from within a WebClip widget.